# MVC @Html.ActionLink no-op from controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an `@Html.ActionLink` inside of a partial view that when clicked I'd like to have either send the user to another view or stay on the current view without changing anything. Is this possible?

Our controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    if (ShouldAllowEdit(id))
    {
      return this.View("Edit", ...edit stuff...)              
    }

    return ????????
}
```

We tried `return new EmptyResult();` but that just dumps the user to a blank page.

Comment: Why is the button available to them to click if it's possible they can't edit?

Comment: Great question @Shoe. This is in support of record locking without some sort of active refresh. Users will be shown that the thing they're trying to edit is currently locked by another user, but if it's state has changed (i.e. been unlocked) since the link was rendered we want to take them to the edit screen when they click the link.

Comment: I think a better approach is to use ajax and on success it redirects from javascript otherwise do nothing. This way everything about the page's state is kept intact if there is a failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little different approach to the issue, but it should do what you want.

Instead of giving the user a link to navigate to, do an ajax call on link/button click, and do the id check. Return either the url to navigate to in a JsonResult, or nothing if the id is invalid.

On return of the ajax call, navigate to the url if appropriate.

(swap out the hard coded ids and the == 0 with your ShouldAllowEdit function in the example of course)

In the View:

```
<div class="btn btn-danger" id="myButton">Button</div>

@section scripts{
<script>
    $("#myButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax("@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = 0 })", { type : "POST" })
            .success(function (data) {
                if (data.url !== "") {
                    window.location.href = data.url;
                }
            });
    });
</script>
}
```

In the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Edit(int id)
{
    if (id == 0)
    {
        return Json(new {url = ""});
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { url = Url.Action("EditPage", new { id = id }) });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This way the page stays in the same state on failure

Comment: We have many edit links on the page so this strategy worked best with `@Ajax.ActionLink` that can be link specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the user clicks a link they *will* be taken away. They might be sent back right to the same page, but the page will unload, be requested from the server again, and then re-rendered in the browser. If you don't want that to happen, you don't give the user the link in the first place. In other words, conditionally render the link or not based on the user's roles or whatever.

```
 @if (userCanEdit)
 {
     @Html.ActionLink(...)
 }
```

Where `userCanEdit` is whatever logic you need to make that determination.

If the user fails whatever check you determine, then they don't get the link. Simple.

However, since there's malicious people in the world, you can't just leave it entirely there. There's potential for the user to figure out the link to edit something and go there manually. So, to prevent that you check for the edit permission in your action (like you've already got in your code sample), but if the user is not allowed, then you just return a forbidden status code:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
```

Or

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(403);
```

They both do the same thing.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment above, it appears that the user is *normally* allowed to edit but can't in a particular instance because another user is editing. A 403 Forbidden is not appropriate in that case, so really all you've got is a simple redirect back to the page they were on, perhaps with a message explaining why they're back there.

```
TempData["EditErrorMessage"] = "Sorry another user is editing that right now.";
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer is to redirect to the view action - and maybe give some feed back why they failed.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    if (ShouldAllowEdit(id))
    {
      return this.View("Edit", ...edit stuff...)              
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("id", "Not allowed to edit this item");
    return RedirectToAction(Edit(id));
}
```